# Get key value from an object while looping

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I am lost on getting the value of height from this object for each person:

```
[object Object] {
  Adam: [object Object] {
    height: 192,
    weight: 101
  },
  Grant: [object Object] {
    height: 171,
    weight: 79
  }
}
```

I just keep getting undefined or printing out the name.

```
  const personData = data
  Object.keys(personData).forEach((person, index) => {
    console.log(person)
  })
```

The above will just console log the name, `person[0]` gives me the first letter of each name and my other attempts produce undefined.

How do I navigate to the correct value and key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're iterating over the root of the object. The height, weight etc details live in sub-objects at a deeper level.

You're going to need to iterate over the object's values, not its keys, then reach in a little deeper to extrac the `height` property:

```
Object.values(personData).forEach((person, index) => {
    console.log('Height = '+person.height);
    //if you need to access the person name too...
    console.log('Person = '+Object.keys(personData)[index]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the keys of the object. In this case "Adam" and "Grant". What you want to do is to use these keys to access the object - and that is your person:

```
const personData = data
Object.keys(personData).forEach((name, index) => {
    console.log(personData[name])
})
```